# Replacing values in one column with another based on a 3rd column matching a 4th

Tags: r, replace

I'm working with the following example:

```
Original     Modified     New_Orig     New
1            2            1            0
2            4            1            0
3            6            4            0
4            8            5            0
5            10           5            0
6            12           5            0
7            14           5            0
8            16           5            0
9            18           9            0
10           20           10           0
```

I want to replace values in `New` with values from `Modified` if `New_Orig` matches with any value in `Original`.

Ideally `New` will look like this:

```
New
2  
2
8
10
10
10
10
10
18
20
```

Any help much appreciated.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here, a new column `New` is created:

```
within(dat, New <- Modified*(New_Orig == Original))

   Original Modified New_Orig New
1         1        2        1   2
2         2        4        1   0
3         3        6        4   0
4         4        8        5   0
5         5       10        5  10
6         6       12        5   0
7         7       14        5   0
8         8       16        5   0
9         9       18        9  18
10       10       20       10  20
```

**Update**

Match values and choose appropriate value from `Modified`:

```
within(dat, New <- Modified[match(New_Orig, Original)])

   Original Modified New_Orig New
1         1        2        1   2
2         2        4        1   2
3         3        6        4   8
4         4        8        5  10
5         5       10        5  10
6         6       12        5  10
7         7       14        5  10
8         8       16        5  10
9         9       18        9  18
10       10       20       10  20
```

Comment: @Arun Sorry, I don't know a reference for this technique. Basically, it's based on type conversion (logical to integer). Hence, `FALSE` becomes `0` and `TRUE` becomes `1`.

Comment: @Arun It *does* work outside `within` or `transform`. Did you get an error?

Comment: @ Sven Hohenstein - thanks for the reply. I've just noticed that this didn't work for all values in 'New'. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: @JPD Could you please clarify the problem?

Comment: @Sven Hohenstein For example, row 2 of 'New' should also be 2 because 'New_Orig' is 1. Row 3 of 'New' should be 8 because 'New_Orig' is 4.

Comment: @JPD In both row 2 and 3, `Original` and `New_Orig` aren't identical. Hence, in these rows `New` is zero. What did I miss?

Comment: @Sven Hohenstein When `Original` is 5, `Modified` is 10. Therefore when `New_Orig` is 5 `New` should be 10 is what I ideally need. I need the value matching to search the whole column and not just be constrained to the one row.

Comment: @Sven Hohenstein Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

Since @rcs gave exactly the answer I would give, I thought I would show you an alternative approach to creating this "New" column rather than initializing it as all zeroes.

```
data <- data.frame(Original = 1:10,
                   Modified = seq(2, 20, 2),
                   New_Orig = c(1, 1, 4, 5, 5, 
                                5, 5, 5, 9, 10))
within(data, {
    New <- ifelse(Original == New_Orig, Modified, 0)
})
#    Original Modified New_Orig New
# 1         1        2        1   2
# 2         2        4        1   0
# 3         3        6        4   0
# 4         4        8        5   0
# 5         5       10        5  10
# 6         6       12        5   0
# 7         7       14        5   0
# 8         8       16        5   0
# 9         9       18        9  18
# 10       10       20       10  20
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
v <- dat$New_Orig==dat$Original # this gives a logical vector,
                                # you could also use which(dat$New_Orig==dat$Original)
                                # to obtain the indices
dat[v, "New"] <- dat[v, "Modified"]
```