# Assign set of values to a column

Tags: r, variable-assignment

I have a column of 5 digit code values (from 1-3) values in R with 243 possible combinations (5 digits, each digit can be 1, 2, or 3):

Example:

```
13212

13211
```

However, each 5 digit code represents a coresponding value.

For instance:

```
13212 = 0.5120

13211 = 0.1232
```

How do I imput the unique corresponding value for each of these 243 numeric codes?

How do I tell R to convert my column of numeric codes into their coresponding values?

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905038/replace-values-in-a-vector-based-on-another-vector

Comment: Hi Roman, I want R to give me a new column with the new value?

Comment: is there any mathematical relation that makes `13212 = 0.5120`
and `13211 = 0.1232` ?

Comment: Assigning result values to a new column is trivial (e.g. my.data$new.data <- my.result`. The "tricky" part is to convert from your factor (or whatever your coding is) to that numeric. Have you tried the solutions in the link I pasted?

Comment: Michele, no mathematical relation, each 5 digit code has a corresponding value that I have from a scoring manual.

Comment: Since you seem to need to input these scores by hand anyway (be your manual pape or digital), make a CSV file and then import it into R using `read.csv`. You can use e.g. Excel to create CSV files.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14232899/replacing-values-in-one-column-with-another-based-on-a-3rd-column-matching-a-4th?rq=1


Credit to Sven Hohenstein for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best solution, but if you want to replace every value1 of a vector with value2:

```
relations=data.frame(value1=c(13212,13211),value2=c(0.5120,0.1232))
values=c(13212,13211)
for (i in 1:length(values)){
   values[i]=relations$value2[relations$value1==values[i]]
}
```